# which default pool type of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-async

I have read the code but did not find the default pool type of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. what is the default thread pool of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor? newFixedThreadPool or newCachedThreadPool?

Comment: [The docs say](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) "The default configuration is a core pool size of 1, with unlimited max pool size and unlimited queue capacity. This is roughly equivalent to `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, sharing a single thread for all tasks."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pure spring application , the default `TaskExecutor` will be resolved in the following orders (source codes [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5e808ad0183a63944ab08017a13cbc7ed75bc581/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java#L156)) :

1. The bean that is `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor`
2. The bean that is `java.util.concurrent.Executor` and with the name
   `taskExecutor`
3. `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`

So if you do not configure anything , by default it will use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which internally does not use JDK 's `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create a thread. So there is no thread pooling and will create a new thread for each async invocation.

For spring-boot application , it will auto-configure a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling)) . As `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is a type of `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor` , it will be used as the default according to the above mentioned order.

`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` internally use JDK 's `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but neither its use `newFixedThreadPool()` nor `newCachedThreadPool()` to create `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Rather it directly call its constructor to create but then configure its setting based on the application properties.(source codes [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b0b2818f0b03bc972fa91f91c1b8290987881811/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.java#L80))

Comment: why spring did not using the jdk thread pool? @Ken Chan I did not find anyone talk about this.

Comment: they use it but in the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor implementation.

Comment: they do suggest if you look for  true pooling, you should use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor instead of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor from the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-task-executor-types)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the java doc of ***ThreadPoolTaskExecutor***:

**From Spring Framework Documentation.**

> The **default configuration** is a core pool size of 1, with unlimited max
> pool size and unlimited queue capacity.
> This is roughly equivalent to **Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()**,
> sharing a single thread for all tasks.

> Setting **"*queueCapacity*"** to 0 mimics **Executors.newCachedThreadPool()**, with > immediate scaling of threads in the pool to a potentially very high number.
> Consider also setting a **"*maxPoolSize*"** at that point, as well as possibly a higher **"*corePoolSize*"** (see also the "**allowCoreThreadTimeOut**" mode of scaling).

***The difference between the three executors:***

**newFixedThreadPool** :
Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks.
If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.
If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.
The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.

**newSingleThreadExecutor** :
Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue.
(Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.)
Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time.
Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

**newCachedThreadPool** :
Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available.
These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available.
If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache.
Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources.
Note that pools with similar properties but different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors.

**Spring Boot Application** :
the default values of properties for AutoConfigure the bean TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration:

```
#Whether core threads are allowed to time out. This enables dynamic 

growing and shrinking of the pool.
spring.task.execution.pool.allow-core-thread-timeout=true

#Core number of threads.
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=8

#Time limit for which threads may remain idle before being terminated.
spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive=60s

#Maximum allowed number of threads. If tasks are filling up the queue, the pool can expand up to that size to accommodate the load. Ignored if the queue is unbounded.
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size=

#Queue capacity. An unbounded capacity does not increase the pool and therefore ignores the "max-size" property.
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity=

#Whether the executor should wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown.
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=false

#Maximum time the executor should wait for remaining tasks to complete.
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=

#Prefix to use for the names of newly created threads.
spring.task.execution.thread-name-prefix=task-

#Maximum allowed number of threads.
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=1

#Whether the executor should wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown.
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination=false

#Maximum time the executor should wait for remaining tasks to complete.
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination-period

#Prefix to use for the names of newly created threads.
spring.task.scheduling.thread-name-prefix=scheduling-
```

Comment: where is the code to decide using which thread pool, like poolSize =0 then using newCachedPool, when poolSize =1 then using singleThreadPool. @evskillup where is the code to do the choosing?

Comment: thanks for the info but we all know that. But for pure spring application , no ThreadPoolTaskExecutor will be created by default. And SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is created instead . See my answer please

Comment: @KenChan the question is about the default pool type of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor not about the default taskExecutor used by spring framework or spring boot.

Comment: @devskillup . ok but apparently the author does not mean to ask that as such info can be easier found by reading the javdoc by ourself. No need to specially open a question to ask that. Also ,he is mentioning about reading the source codes , and based on the  following questions that he ask you (although you did not reply him) , he is more interested to know about how spring application create the thread pool by default.

Comment: @Dolphin there is no explicit code to do that, it's just the equivalent!